# User menu fade in and out on hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouseover, mouseout

I have user menus that need to fade in and out on the mouse over and mouse out of an icon. My problem is that the user should also be able to hover over the menu (or img in this case) and not have the menu fade out so that they can click on the links or image within. Here is my code and a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/7mrM2/

```
<style>
div.notif
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:8px;
    background-color:white;
}
a.notif:hover + div.notif
{
    display:block;

}
div.notif:hover
{
    display:block;

}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//NOT WORKING
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(".notif").hover(
      function () {
        $('.notif').fadeIn('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $('.notif').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});
});//]]>  
</script>//NOT WORKING
</head>
<body>
<a class="notif" href="notifications.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="images/bubble.png" style="position:relative; top:20px;"/></a>
    <div class="notif" style="z-index:999999; ">
<a href="notifications.html"><img src="images/notif.png"/></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Link the images in the fiddle from the website. Working with broken images is not easy... Also, in jsFiddle, you have to set jQuery as the framework. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/7mrM2/1/)

Comment: You can't hover on something that isn't hoverable. `fadeOut` ends with  `display:none`!!! From this point on what are you hovering so that it `fadeIn`?  Nothing!

Comment: I can take away the code that fades in or out, i just thought it would be helpful. I've used it before, just when you hover over the (newly faded in) menu, it dissapears because you mouseout of the icon to focus on the menu.

Comment: fiddle updated with pictures

Comment: What is the link to the updated fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/7mrM2/7/

Comment: Check my answer.. Seems like that will help you..

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. See [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mrM2/13/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='parent'>
   <a class="notif" href="notifications.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg" height="30" width="30"/></a>

   <div class="notif" style="z-index:999999; ">
      <a href="notifications.html"><img src="http://doinghistoryproject.tripod.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/failure-message.gif" height="80" width="80"/></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".parent").hover(
    function () {
       $(this).find('div.notif').stop().fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function () {
       $(this).find('div.notif').stop().fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Wolf! We meet again. This works great, with only one hover menu. What if I want let's say 3? If you add more than one, with different ids, they will summon each other. Strange.

Comment: Well, I copied what you have and you can see they are glitchy .http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/7mrM2/12/

Comment: Fiddle #13, right? Still the same issue. If you hover on one it shows both or mouseout it shows one or the other. Something is clearly disagreeing somewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23255/discussion-between-wolf-and-triplethreat77)